# How to use Go / GORM to print SELECT query output without pre-defined struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am developing an API using `Go` which connects to MySQL database for some query execution. Am using `GORM` for database operations. But am stuck at printing the `SELECT` query output for the tables which I don't have the column names.

My use case is that, I need to run the query on multiple tables where I don't have an idea about what their column names and types are. And so I cannot pre-define a struct for all the current and future tables which might get added.

Is there a way to print/save the `SELECT` query output without a pre-defined `struct` ?

I tried do some using empty struct but it didn't help me.

P.S: Am a beginner in Go

```
    type Testing struct{}

    var test Testing
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v@tcp(%v:%v)/%v", myds.DBuser, myds.DBpassword, myds.DBhost, myds.DBport, myds.DBname)
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    tx := db.Raw(query).Scan(&test)
    if tx.Error != nil {
        fmt.Println(tx.Error)
    }
    fmt.Println(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me by using a map type with interface. This helped me to save the `SELECT` query results without pre-defined struct or the column names.

```
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v@tcp(%v:%v)/%v", myds.DBuser, myds.DBpassword, myds.DBhost, myds.DBport, myds.DBname)

    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var result []map[string]interface{}

    tx := db.Raw(query).Scan(&result)
    if tx.Error != nil {
        fmt.Println(tx.Error)
        return
    }
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(result)
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **anonymous** struct

Let's say you have a **struct**:

```
type User struct{
  FirstName string
  LastName string
}
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,last_name) AS full_name from users;
```

*Notice the new column `full_name`*

you can simply do

```
var fullName = struct{FullName string}{}
```

***Notice how I use pascal case & FullName has to be the field name***
A capital letter in between will represent a `_`
Field is public so it can be accessed outside.

**full_name**(query) = **FullName**(field)

pass this fullName object as a bucket to your Scan and it should work.

db.Raw(query).Scan(&fullName)

**EDIT**:

Your query will have some result right?
Let me assume that you have

```
column_one,column_two... column_n
```

Now, to get the data from all the columns or *selected ones* if you want, you simply have to define fields (in anonymous struct) with specific names. In our case:

```
struct{ColumnOne,ColumnTwo,..ColumnN interface{}}{}
```

P.S. I have used `interface{}`, you can use types depending on the data your column returns.

Comment: Let me explain with an example to suit my requirement.
Let's say my `query="SELECT * FROM employee"` and my table has `(name, age, city, address)` as fields. 

The point here is that I don't have these field names of the table. The API might connect to 10 different tables and I don't/can't have struct defined for all. 

Your example has a struct with FirstName and LastName which are equivalent to the existing column names.

In simple, I want to execute select queries on multiple tables and save it's result who's column names are unknown.

Comment: @GopiKumar check edit

Comment: I am still unable to understand the solution using anonymous struct and interface since am a beginner. My bad. Thanks for the suggestion but I tried using dynamic map object and it worked for me ! See the other comment.